# Sprite Kit equivalent of CCTexture2D

Tags: sprite-kit

I have been toying with this on and off for days, and I still cannot do it…

Does anyone know what the equivalent of the below code would be in Sprite Kit??

I use this snippet of code literally thousands of times in all my games… and if it is 'unconvertible'  I am not even going to attempt Sprite Kit at all….

```
CCTexture2D *hintA7Vert = [[CCTexture2D alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:pipeName]  resolutionType: kCCResolutionUnknown];
[movablePipeHintVertA7 setTexture: hintA7Vert];
[hintA7Vert release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in the [API reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013027)?

```
SKTexture* texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:pipeName]];

// or more directly without the (unnecessary) conversion through UIImage
SKTexture* texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:pipeName];

// then use the texture
yourSprite.texture = texture;
// or
SKSpriteNode* sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
```

Your HD resolution image should have the `@2x` suffix btw, not cocos2d's `-hd`.

Comment: Thanks… I was using the -hd suffix.  Good luck on your Kobold Sprite Kit.  I hope you are successful.  Appreciate the answer.